# Responsive wrapping of columns with different width ratios (float, flex, grid)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there a way to specify column width ratios and minimum widths to allow wrapping for narrow screens (responsive design)?

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1/3 |    2/3    |
|     |(1/3 | 1/3)|
+-----+-----+-----+

+-----+-----+
| 1/3 | 1/3 |       (actual ratio now 1/2)
|     | 1/3 |
+-----+-----+

+-----+
| 1/3 |             (actual ratio now 1 - full width)
+-----+
| 1/3 |
| 1/3 |
+-----+
```

Each `1/3` is a div, so is `2/3`.
It should fill 100% of its parent's width (centered "main" container column).

I've tried the following:

- "classic" float: did not get it right
- flexbox: close, but uneven sizes
- grid: sizes well, but doesn't wrap?

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
}

#container>div {
  float: left;
}

#container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex>div {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.fone {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.ftwo {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.gthree {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.gtwo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
float: not quite right
<div id="container">
  <div style="width:33%;">A</div>
  <div style="width:66%;">
    <div style="width:50%;">B</div>
    <div style="width:50%;">C</div>
  </div>
</div>

flex: wraps, uneven sizing, children overflow
<div class="flex">
  <div class="fone">A</div>
  <div class="ftwo flex">
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</div>

grid: nice sizing, but does not wrap
<div class="gthree">
  <div>A</div>
  <div class="gtwo">
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</div>

Intended result:
<div class="one">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Which method is suited for my purpose?
- How would it be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect, but you can get really close with grids and `auto-fit` [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat#auto-fit)
and `minmax`.

We set the min value in our min max to the width it'll wrap after, and the max to `1fr` for the cells to flex with the grid.

The issue is `repeat()` with `auto-fit` sets an equal ratio between all columns, so **A** will be as big as B & C until everything wraps together. Which is fine for scenarios 2 and 3 but not 1.

This could be fixed by using flex and and setting the flex-grow's accordingly so that when everything's in one line, the ratios are correct, but then in the other scenarios the ratios would have to go change again, which is an issue.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.inner { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class='single'>A</div>
  <div class='inner'>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like with grid I might have to live with the 1/4 width "tracks" unless there's a way to work around the changing ratios (1/3 and 2/3 ... 1/2 ... 1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  /* Or you can use any of the 
   following as per needs:
justify-content:space-between;
justify-content:space-around;
justify-content:space-evenly;
justify-content:center; */
}

.inner { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex:1;
}
.middle { 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex:1;

}
.single{
/* For occupying equal space: */
  flex:1;
  
}


/* `Note: The flex-wrap works when you use a specific width, else the width will adjust automatically depends on screen size` */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='single'>A</div>
  <div class='middle'>
    <div class='inner'>B</div>
    <div class='inner'>C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this also results in quarter columns (not thirds), and it does not demonstrate wrapping.

Comment: For wrapping you can give the width of the div of A ,B & C to something like 250px... So on small screen it automatically wraps... Or you can use bootstrap if you don't wan't to give specific width.

Answer (score 0):

Flex proportions work well in my application.
The actual contents have (different) widths, so they may shrink and overflow at different screen widths.
I have added minimum size values for flex in an attempt to simulate that. It does not work well here in the Snippet.

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap:1rem;">
  <div style="flex:1 250px;">AAA unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</div>
  <div style="flex:2; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap:1rem;">
    <div style="flex:1 250px;">BBB unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</div>
    <div style="flex:1 250px;">CCC unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,</div>
  </div>
</div>
```